# Simple Html Dom Parsing multiple image inside table

Tags: php, dom

I have this code:

```
    require('simple_html_dom.php');
    $xurl=('https://example.com/pics/flower.php');
    $html = file_get_html($xurl);
    $articles = [];
    $i = 0;

   foreach ($html->find('div.gallery-a -> *') as $article) {
   if ($i > 22) {
                break;
        }

    $title = $html->find('div.gallery-a -> table -> tr.*[id] -> td -> a', $i)->plaintext;
    $url = $html->find('div.gallery-a -> table -> tr.*[id] -> td -> a', $i)->href;
    $images = $html->find('div.gallery-a -> table ->td -> table -> tr -> img',$i)->src;

    $item['Title'] = $title;
    $item['link'] = $url;
    $item['image'] = $images;

    $articles[] = $item;
    $i++;
    }


    $result = json_encode($articles, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);        

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-type: Application/JSON');
    echo $result;
```

And here is the html code to parse: https://pastebin.com/uj4YHiHt

Im trying to scraping data from one site with php simple html dom,
this site are using very little class or id on its source code
so I had trouble finding the right code to get the results I wanted

I'm able to manage 2 items with the correct result (**Title** and **url**), but I have difficulty with the **images** items that are inside the table.
Here the result if I try to get the image with the loop.

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Tulip flower under the rainbow",
        "link": "\/gallery.php?id=345",
        "image": "https://example.com/images/tulip1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Red Rose flower",
        "link": "\/gallery.php?id=346",
        "image": "https://example.com/images/tulip2.jpg"
    },
```

Expected result

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Tulip flower under the rainbow",
        "link": "\/gallery.php?id=345",
        "image1": "https://example.com/images/tulip1.jpg"
        "image2": "https://example.com/images/tulip2.jpg"
        "image3": "https://example.com/images/tulip3.jpg"
        "image4": "https://example.com/images/tulip4.jpg"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Red Rose flower",
        "link": "\/gallery.php?id=346",
        "image1": "https://example.com/images/rose1.jpg"
        "image2": "https://example.com/images/rose2.jpg"
        "image3": "https://example.com/images/rose3.jpg"
        "image4": "https://example.com/images/rose4.jpg"
    },
```

Please help.

Comment: `foreach (images` and?

Comment: @u_mulder sorry, i have fix it

Comment: Don't see any fixes.

Comment: @u_mulder fix now

Comment: @miken32 yes, i know, everytime i point the foreach its give me another problem, that's why i point directly from the "find" but it also give me another problem.